# Elasticsearch custom analyzer with two output tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer, elasticsearch-6

Requirement is to create a custom analyzer which can generate two tokens as shown in below scenarios.

E.g.

```
Input -> B.tech in
Output Tokens ->
- btechin
- b.tech in
```

I am able to remove non-alphanumeric character, but how to retain original one too in the output token list. Below is the custom analyzer that I have created.

```
       "alphanumericStringAnalyzer": {
            "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "minLength_filter"],
            "char_filter": [
                "specialCharactersFilter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }

      "char_filter": {
        "specialCharactersFilter": {
            "pattern": "[^A-Za-z0-9]",
            "type": "pattern_replace",
            "replacement": ""
        }
      },
```

This analyzer is generating single token "btechin" for input "B.tech in" but I also want original one too in token list "B.tech in"

Thanks!

Comment: I think its not possible, you can create another field and copy the value of this field into it and pass it to keyword tokenizer ? also it would help why you need this functionality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the word token delimiter as described in this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html)

Here an example of word delimiter configuration :

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "B.tech in",
  "tokenizer": "keyword",
  "filter": [
    "lowercase",
    {
      "type": "word_delimiter",
      "catenate_all": true,
      "preserve_original": true,
      "generate_word_parts": false
    }
  ]
}
```

results :

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "b.tech in",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "btechin",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope it will fulfill your requirements!